# What would be a good way to structure endpoints to provide quiz-like functionality?

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

Imagine you have Questions and Answers db tables with the following fields:

**Questions**
- id
- text

**Answers**
- id
- question (foreign key to Questions table)
- text
- is_correct (shows whether this answer is correct one)

The API consumer would want to retrieve questions with possible answers, also there has to be a way for consumer to supply an answer for a given question and on backend we would determine whether it was the correct answer or not and store it in some Progress table.

Here is my initial idea:
`/questions/` - on GET returns all questions and their possible answers.
Example

```
[
{
  "id": "24",
  "text": "Can people fly?",
  "answers": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "text": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "text": "No"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "text": "Really complex answer"
    }
  ]
},
...
]
```

`/questions/<question_id>/answer` - POST request with answer id to submit an answer for a given question.
My main concern is the use of verb "answer" in this endpoint. I think it does not follow the REST convention where we have to use nouns over verbs when designing endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main concern is the use of verb "answer" in this endpoint. I think it does not follow the REST convention where we have to use nouns over verbs when designing endpoints.

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for the identifiers for your resources.

/questions//answer
   /questions//12345
   /questions//correct-horse-battery-staple
   /bdeee0e1-9094-4c8d-a35a-aee971106534

Those are all perfectly find *identifiers*; REST doesn't care -- general purpose clients don't attempt to extract semantic information from the identifier.

BUT...

The spelling that you are using suggests that you aren't really thinking about the resources themselves.  In HTTP, the core idea is that we are [passing documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s).

This means that you can often try to imagine your problem implemented using pen and paper.  So imagine a school classroom receiving a quiz -- each student receives a piece of paper with a list of questions, and blanks for the student to add her answer.  The student modifies the document by providing answers.

So your "resource" in this case is probably something like the piece of paper for the quiz -- not the master copy with the correct answers, but the student's copy with blank answers that get filled in.

Thus, you would likely have a different resource for each student taking the quiz

```
/quiz/12345/alice
/quiz/12345/bob
```

Of course, the entire quiz could be spread out over multiple resources, which is closer to your current model:

```
/question/67890/alice
/question/67890/bob
```

[Resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) is a really important concept in HTTP

> Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on.

If you are having trouble finding a good identifier for a resource, that is often evidence that you don't actually understand what the information is, and how to name it.  So concentrate on getting that clear in your mind first.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. Unfortunately, I have supplied the wrong example: there should be no indicator in response whether answer is correct or not. I want my quizzes to be multiple-choice ones. But, anyway, you have set me on the right track, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who also wonders how to design the API for their quiz system, [Canvas LMS](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/) has a well documented API (check out Quiz related sections). Maybe their practices can inspire and/or influence yours:)
Hope it helps!